# execute a command in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to execute a DOS command from javascript.
Please help me.

Comment: You don't.  That would be a serious violation of browser security.

Comment: What kind of JavaScript are you talking about?  You can't really run DOS commands from JavaScript running inside a browser without jumping through a lot of hoops (if at all).  You will probably have to add more clarification before anyone will attempt to answer this question.

Comment: I don't think you can even do that since JS runs in a browser sandbox. I'd be terrified of the web if that kind of stuff were allowed!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run commands from javascript if you are a mozilla add-on using xpcom.

Take a look at this.
http://jsdoodnauth.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/run-external-apps-using-xpcom-interfaces/

Basically browsers run javascript in a sandbox so scripts can't damage the local computer. To run scripts you have to create a custom made solution for your browser and install it locally so you can get outside the sandbox.